# Render an object's key and values via a component and v-for in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Essentially I have an object whose keys and values are altered via other functions.

```
app=new Vue({
    ...
    data:{
        myObject:{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}
    }
})
```

I wrote a component which receives them as props and displays them.

```
Vue.component("my-component",{
    props:['k','v'],
    template:`
        <div>{{k}}:{{v}}</div>
    `    
})
```

Now, when I write this:

```
<my-component v-for="(value,key) in myObject" v-bind:k="key" v-bind:v="value"></my-component>
```

And execute `app.myObject['someKey']='some value'` nothing happens and without any console message, even when in development mode.
Where am I going wrong? Or is there a better way to render an object's key and values via a component?

Edit:
Something I observed, when the object is already is populated in the data object, it renders perfectly. However when an outside function modifies it, the changes are not reflected **unless** I modify a key's value which value which was already present in the object.

Edit2:
https://jsfiddle.net/agentrsdg/xs635ndk/8/

Answer (score 3):

Loop for children in Object like below.

```
<div v-for="(value, key, index) in object">
```

So for your codes.

```
<my-component
  v-for="(value, key) in myObject"
  v-bind:key-prop="key" // prop name in my-component is keyProp but use key-prop in the parent component
  v-bind:value-Prop="value"
/>
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AntonioCollins/kbwgns5d/3/) for my answer.

Comment: Not working, also edited the question accordingly (simplified the prop names)

Comment: That question specifies an array of objects, not an object. Also, I updated the question with regards to naming scheme of the props.

Comment: I didn't. When there's an error in the code, VueJS development version prints a message in the console on its own.

Comment: It's nothing, also I noticed an interesting thing, check the new edit.

Comment: check the latest edit. Add `<button onclick="app.myObject['k']='v'">This is the issue</button>` to your code and see.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do? What is your purpose? And there's no event like `onclick`, use `@click`. and "app.myObject[k] = v".

Comment: `@click` doesn't work either.  I updated your JSFiddle accordingly as well.. What I am trying to do, as stated in the question, is to display an object's keys and values (not just predefined, but also those which are added at runtime via other functions) through a component using v-for.

Comment: Right after the <div id="app">

Comment: Please see my updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/AntonioCollins/kbwgns5d/3/

Comment: Again, the issue is not with predefined keys. It is with adding new ones. Try adding a new key during runtime as done in https://jsfiddle.net/agentrsdg/xs635ndk/8/

Comment: Check this out. https://jsfiddle.net/AntonioCollins/c39vn5rf/

Comment: **Now** you specify `$set` eh?

Answer (score -1):

So I thought I discovered a bug and an issue on github(https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/10611), and they were quick to respond with the solution. The above not working is a limitation of JavaScript itself. So one should use,

```
app.$set(app.myObject,'newKey','newValue)
```

or

```
Vue.set(app.myObject,'newKey','newValue')
```

More details here : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Object-Change-Detection-Caveats